# Measuring distance between two points using google api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to measure the distance between a marker and a point that has been searched for by postcode. The idea is to make markers appear within a certain radius. as far as I can tell I've done it right but clearly not.

The current code for the function looks like this:

```
    function setup_map(latitude, longitude) {
        var _position = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 14,
            center: _position
        }

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

        @foreach (var i in ViewData.Model)
        {
            <text>

        var markerPos = {lat: @i.Lat, lng:@i.Long}

        var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(markerPos, _position);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker
            ({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng (markerPos),
                map: map,
                title: "" + (@i.id),
            });

            </text>
        }

    }
```

This function reloads the map and all the markers on it. At the minute I'm not too concerned with loading the markers within the radius. I just want to load them all.

When you click the search button, the map loads to the postcode entered but doesn't load any markers. If I remove the "var distance" line, it still goes to the postcode and loads all of the markers. So by process of elimination, there must be something wrong with this line but I have no idea what.

Comment: What does the generated HTML/javascript look like (in the browser)?  What "postcode button"?  Are you including the geometry library?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.